# Compiling multiple C++ files together versus sepearately

Tags: c++, compilation

for large C++ projects, is it better to compile all cpp files in one big call of g++ or compile them all separately and then link the result or maybe something inbetween (like compiling all files of a namespace/module/subdirectory at once).

What is the actual difference? Which method is fastest and why?

Comment: What happened when you tried it with your code and your machine? Which was fastest for you?

Comment: well, the current state of my project is too small to yield big differences. However, the project will grow and thus I want to do it correctly right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling files seperately and then linking is the better practice, because it allows you to recompile only affected files in case of a modification. Hence the build time is minimized after the first build.

Actually makefiles are prepared most of the time using this approach, for the said reason.

Comment: okay, but arent all required header files then read more often? In the compile together approach, frequently used headers like <string> are only read once, right? Isn't that of any importance?

Comment: I am not really sure about gcc reading headers only once while using the other approach, could not find any documentation stating that either. However, in a big project setup where you change a few files and build often, the difference is significant.

Comment: well if it is one compile pass then the headers should be called only once since they are usually guarded by ifndef/define directives

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick. Say you have a bunch of files

```
file1.cpp
file2.cpp
... 
fileN.cpp
```

Then you can create the "master.cpp" file:

```
#include "file1.cpp"
#include "file2.cpp"
...
#include "fileN.cpp"
```

and compile it.

This way you can easily compare build times for individual files and the file bunch.

If you're on UNIX, use the "time" to get the execution time of gcc call.

And, of course, the bottleneck is the "gather" operation - linking stage. There's a GOLD linker ( [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29) ) which solves this for ELF files.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, the first run will be different than subsequent runs.  Usually, the "all in one" compiles faster the first time, but then if you make a single change, the seperate files will compile _significantly_ faster than the "all in one" file.

Comment: Sure, this is for the stable "release" rebuild-alls, where there are no typos or small changes. Also, the overhead of invoking the 'gcc' multiple times diminishes in the case with a single file.

Comment: But the speed gain in application execution code (which is ultimate target, isn't it?) isn't negligible.

Comment: Which one yields a faster application? Shouldn't both approaches produce the same code ultimately?

Comment: @gexicide: Linkers have trouble optimizing, so the "all in one" will usually be _slightly_ faster.  But I think the difference is minuscule, and most people consider it not worth the trouble of an "all in one" file.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, launching multiple compiler processes in parallel will lead to more efficient CPU usage, given that you're on a multi-core or multi-CPU system. The main bottleneck for the whole project is still the linker which actually has to create an executable from all the object files, however.

Other than that, it really depends on the project itself. How many dependencies are there between the files? Which ones need to be compiled first? You're best off letting your build system make those decisions for you.

Comment: okay, so there is no common practice which favors either of them?